# CKEditor 5 en Laravel 8, falla al subir imagen con aplicación en producción

Tags: laravel, imagen, ckeditor

de antemano agradezco el apoyo que me brinden en la publicación...

Tengo un problema que solo me está pasando en mi aplicación web cuando está en producción.
Estoy usando el CDN de CKEditor 5 en su versión 29.0.0 en mi proyecto de Laravel 8.

Estoy usando la función personalizada para subir imágenes al servidor (SimpleUploadAdapterPlugin) y en el código que tengo en mi computadora funciona perfectamente, el problema radica en que al subir el mismo proyecto a mi hosting, falla la subida de imágenes, generándome el error por defecto que tiene dicho plugin:

```
const genericErrorText = `No se pudo subir el archivo: ${file.name}.`;
```

Alguien sabe a qué se debe esto? Gracias.

Comment: ¿Que error exacto te esta arrojando?, podrías revisar el **log** de *Laravel*

Comment: Buenas, muchas gracias, el error del log es: [2021-07-16 13:50:16] production.ERROR: Unable to create the "/public_html/escolaricep/storage/imagenesContenido" directory. Es un error raro, porque dicha carpeta ya está creada y no solo eso, actualmente ya subo archivos .pdf a la misma carpeta sin problemas.

Comment: Por lo que veo estas usando una ruta absoluta `/public_html/...` prueba sin la diagonal del inicio `public_html/...`

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, basándome en lo que me dijiste, estuve cambiando constantemente la ruta del AppServiceProvider en el método register(), lo tenía como '/public_html/proyecto' y lo dejé con la ruta completa del hosting, funcionó al hacer dicho cambio, aún así me sigue pareciendo inexplicable el error, ya que como dije antes, yo ya guardaba archivos .pdf y usaba la variable public_path para todo y nunca falló. Como sea, muchas gracias por tu ayuda, me has salvado.

Comment: Me parece perfecto..!! si tienes algo de tiempo y lo deseas, edita y agrega el código que usas para eso en la pregunta. así como la parte que fallaba y la que no, como dices; y con gusto te explico en una respuesta el por que